# Window constantly opens off screen, moving the screen and closing at right window does not work

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I have a dual-screen setup. One screen used to be on the left side, then I changed it to the right side, which created all problems.

Now, I have a window that constantly opens off screen. I can move the window to the desired place using `alt+space` and `move`, but after I close it next time it again opens off-screen.

I think the problem is because the window that opens off-screen is a sub-window for another window. Meaning that there is a window on the second screen, and sup-window is a settings window of the original window. I can change where the original window opens, but I am stuck with the sub-window.

Is there any way to reset where all windows open? I would greatly appreciate any help!

I am using Windows 10

Edit: If I change the screen to the right, then the sub-window opens properly. But again moving and closing the sub-window on another place does not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a Windows issue and there is no "general fix" for this.
It is a design flaw or bug in the program itself in the way it deals with windows-placement.

So file a complaint with the vendor of the application (if possible).

Having said that: Some programs keep a list of previously used windows-positions in a configuration file or in the registry.
Sometimes you can edit those manually to more sane values.
Typical places to look are the registry under HKLM\Software and/or HKCU\Software, .INI files in the program-folder of the program (sometimes also found in C:\windows) and other config-files (often with a .CFG, .CONF or .PREFS extension) in the program-folder.

Always keep a backup of what was originally in there in case your changes didn't work as expected. And ONLY make such changes when the application itself is NOT running.

Comment: I was also thinking that it is because of the ill-designed program, I will try to contact them and get a solution from them. Thanks